# css dynamically angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Estou tendo um problema ao registrar meu css dinamico tentei deixar extensão .scss e .css mas ambas não deram certo.

Theme.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ACTIVE_THEME, Theme, THEMES } from '../models/symbols';

@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {

  themeChange = new EventEmitter<Theme>();

  constructor(
    @Inject(THEMES) public themes: Theme[],
    @Inject(ACTIVE_THEME) public theme: string
  ) {
  }

  getTheme(name: string) {
    const theme = this.themes.find(t => t.name === name);
    if (!theme) {
      throw new Error(`Theme not found: '${name}'`);
    }
    return theme;
  }

  getActiveTheme() {
    return this.getTheme(this.theme);
  }

  getProperty(propName: string) {
    return this.getActiveTheme().properties[propName];
  }

  setTheme(name: string) {
    this.theme = name;
    this.themeChange.emit( this.getActiveTheme());
  }

  registerTheme(theme: Theme) {
    this.themes.push(theme);
  }

  updateTheme(name: string, properties: { [key: string]: string; }) {
    const theme = this.getTheme(name);
    theme.properties = {
      ...theme.properties,
      ...properties
    };

    if (name === this.theme) {
      this.themeChange.emit(theme);
    }
  }

}
```

symbols.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const THEMES = new InjectionToken('THEMES');
export const ACTIVE_THEME = new InjectionToken('ACTIVE_THEME');

export interface Theme {
  name: string;
  properties: any;
}

export interface ThemeOptions {
  themes: Theme[];
  active: string;
}
```

theme.ts

```
import { Theme } from './symbols';

export const lightTheme: Theme = {
  name: 'light',
  properties: {
    '--background': '#f6f7f9',
    '--on-background': '#E74E3C',
    '--primary': '#1976d2',
    '--on-primary': '#fff',
    '--secondary': '#a8a8a8',
    '--on-secondary': '#fff',
    '--surface': '#fff',
    '--on-surface': '#000',
    '--error': '#E74E3C',
    '--on-error': '#fff'
  }
};
```

ThemeDirective.ts

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Theme } from '../../models/symbols';
import { ThemeService } from '../../services/theme.service';


@Directive({
  selector: '[theme]'
})
export class ThemeDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private _destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private _themeService: ThemeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const active = this._themeService.getActiveTheme();
    if (active) {
      this.updateTheme(active);
    }

    this._themeService.themeChange
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe((theme: Theme) => this.updateTheme(theme));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }

  updateTheme(theme: Theme) {
    // project properties onto the element
    for (const key in theme.properties) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty(key, theme.properties[key]);
    }

    // remove old theme
    for (const name of this._themeService.theme) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove(`${name}-theme`);
    }

    // alias element with theme name
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add(`${theme.name}-theme`);
  }

}
```

AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { UtilModule } from './common/utils/util.module';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomInterceptor } from './common/interceptors/http.interceptor';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { ThemeModule } from './common/directives/themes/theme.module';
import { lightTheme } from './common/models/light-theme';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    UtilModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    JwtModule,
    ThemeModule.forRoot({
      themes: [lightTheme],
      active: 'light'
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

meus modulos e todo conteudo para ter meu css dinamico porém não está funcionando, o resultado é esse onde o botão deveria estar da cor #f6f7f9 . Alguém consegue ajudar ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]